# No date written on 'admitted until' stamp on my passport while entering the US on immigrant Visa F41

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

On entering USA as a F41 immigrant visa holder, the immigration officer stamped  my passport and verbally told me that it will be valid for 1 year (during which PR card will processed) but he didn't wrote any validity date. Now i have to travel in and out of USA. Do i need to be concerned and what Should be done in this case?

Comment: There's no "admit until" date because you never have to leave. That's what *permanent* resident means.

Comment: @phoog Make the comment an answer, collect the upvotes. ;)

Comment: I have no idea why this was closed. It's clearly about _traveling_ as a new permanent resident, not about immigration or residence.

Answer (score 8):

When you first enter the US on an *immigrant* visa, the immigration officer will [stamp your passport and visa together](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/temporary-i-551-stamps-and-mrivs), so that the stamp is partly on the passport page and partly on the immigrant visa. This is called an endorsement.

The endorsement stamp activates the clause printed on your visa that states: "UPON ENDORSEMENT SERVES AS TEMPORARY I-551 EVIDENCING PERMANENT RESIDENCE FOR 1 YEAR."

Thus, it's not necessary to write a validity date on the passport stamp. Your stamped visa is good for re-entry for one year, and is evidence that you are a *permanent* resident. An "admit until" date would be senseless.

During that one year period, you may enter the US as a lawful permanent resident using the endorsed visa, as many times as you wish, exactly the same as the permanent resident card you will soon receive. You may use the  immigration lanes designated for lawful permanent residents, at the ports of entry where they are available.

(And note that the endorsement stamp is valid even if it is stamped next to the visa, rather than across it.)

Comment: Curious, when entering on a US visa (any type), do they usually stamp partially on the visa, or on the neighbouring page?

Comment: @Crazydre the first time you use a visa you'll normally get a stamp like that.

Comment: I agree with Michael. Its about travelling. :(